# SharePoint 2010 – Replace Default New or Edit Form With SP Designer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

Having created a web page that is just simple HTML (with JScript to "bring it to life") in SharePoint Designer, how can I cause SP ’10 to present this page for the "New" action? Or the "Edit" action?

This page is not associated with the Master Page/Content paradigm.  It is at WebSite/Lists/TheTargetList/TheTargetForm.aspx

When I show the list properties tab for this list in Designer, and go to the "Forms" section (subtitled "Forms are used to display and edit data contained within this list"), and click the "New..." button at the right of that section's title bar and fill in the Title with the title of my file, I cannot add the file.  (The bread crumbs at the top say "Site > Lists and Libraries > ListName > ")

Alternately, I go to the bottom of the tab's page, and select the link "Item" under Content Types (the choices being "Item" & "Folder").

Then the bread crumbs say "Site > Lists and Libraries > ListName > Content Types > Item >"

In the "Forms" section, I try to put the fully qualified name of the page I have created (my .aspx file) in the "New Form:" or "Edit Form:" areas, after having clicked the "" links. This lets me save that change, but destroys the web site's ability to show anything when I try to go to New or Edit — essentially "File not found."  The same if I provide only the file name, *not* fully qualified.

So, if I have "Site/Lists/List/XYZ.aspx," and if that file is essentially like:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script> . . .  </script>
</head>
<body> . . . <br /> . . . </body>
</html>
```

How can I get this file to be opened as the "New" or "Edit" form for the list?

Answer (score 0):

For reasons totaly beyond my ken, SharePoint designer, which had not been allowing me to insinuate my own custom page, now lets me do so.

Apparently SPD had a small stroke, and took a little while to regain functionality.